# Extjs 4.2.1: How to change remote combo on form load

Tags: json, forms, extjs, combobox

I want to update few combos (with remote json store) on the form panel.
When I simply click the combo (before loading form data), it works well, loading and showing valid items.
But when I do MyForm.getForm().load(...) combo item changes to "2". This is ID but not the value.

Help me please, how to correctly update such combo and show the value with specific id which came in json?

Model:

```
   Ext.define('OwnerUserModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'VarName', type: 'string' }
        ]
    });
```

Store:

```
    var OwnerUserStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model   : 'OwnerUserModel',
        autoSync: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'http://localhost/1/Super.php?Action=GetObjectFormParams&GetAgents=1',
            reader: 'json'
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

Form Panel with combo item:

```
    var MyForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        header: false,
        title: 'My super Form',
        //height: 300,
        url: 'Super.php',
        //width: 1100,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
             ...
             {
             fieldLabel  : 'Agent',
                allowBlank  : false,
                name        : 'OwnerUserId',
                id          : 'OwnerUserId',
                queryParam  : 'GetAgents',
                displayField: 'VarName',
                valueField  : 'id',
                xtype       : 'combo',
                store       : OwnerUserStore,
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                    '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{VarName}</div>',
                    '</tpl>'
                ),
                width: 353,
                padding:  '0 0 0 30',
                editable: false
            }
```

Json reply on store load:

```
[{"id":"1","VarName":"89031230000 user1 phone"},{"id":"2","VarName":"89161200000 user2 phone"
}]
```

Comment: Json reply on form.load is: {"success":true,"data":{"LoadedObjectId":"10","OwnerUserId":"2",......}}

Comment: I think, it's mistake in your `form.load` responce. `OwnerUserId` should be an object with satructure like in your `store.load` request

Comment: I think the [setValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue) function on the combo box may be what you're after.

_Sets the specified value(s) into the field. For each value, if a record is found in the store that matches based on the valueField, then that record's displayField will be displayed in the field. If no match is found, and the valueNotFoundText config option is defined, then that will be displayed as the default field text. Otherwise a blank value will be shown, although the value will still be set._

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the structure of the item and it start to work!

It seems to me that there was some misconfiguration in store or model description...

But I can't understand what exactly:-) What's the difference? Any suggestions?

```
{
                    fieldLabel  : 'Agent',
                    xtype       : 'combo',
                    id          : 'OwnerUserId',
                    name        : 'OwnerUserId',
                    triggerAction:  'all',
                    forceSelection: true,
                    editable    : false,
                    allowBlank  : false,
                    queryParam  : 'GetAgents',
                    mode        : 'remote',
                    displayField:'VarName',
                    valueField  : 'id',
                    width       : 353,
                    padding     :  '0 0 0 30',
                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        fields: [
                            {name: 'id'},
                            {name: 'VarName'}
                        ],
                        autoLoad: true,
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: 'http://localhost/1/Super.php?Action=GetObjectFormParams&GetAgents=1',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
                }
```